# When "by" is used in "Have you ever been bitten by a dog?", why is there an "a" before "dog"?

Tags: prepositions, articles, nouns

I read a sentence:

> Have you ever been bitten by a dog?

but usually when we use "by" we don't put a/the/my before "*noun*". Why did we do that here?

Comment: 'By' takes the indefinite article or a numeral before a count usage (and sometimes the indefinite article before a non-count one): _He was chased by a dog / He was chased by three dogs / He was overwhelmed by a paralysing horror._ Usually, non-count usages are anarthrous or take 'some': _He's being killed by kindness / The crops were saved by some warmer weather_.

Comment: I think that you see a difference in "I was bitten by a dog" and "I went to London by bus/train/boat". The difference is that "dog" is countable and refers to a real dog, but "bus/train/boat" are, in this context, uncountable - "bus/train/boat" describe means of transport, and not an actual bus/train/boat.

Comment: Try saying aloud "I was bitten by dog." If you're not hearing the need for an article there, work on that. Go listen to natives speak. Understand how dog (in this case, a particular dog) differs from other kinds of nouns. Then you will see what when you reference something specific or particular, you'll need that article.

Comment: "a"  is used because it is a general statement, it is not: I was bitten by the dog on the street. [correction: explain **to** me]

Answer (score 1):

"but usually when we use 'by' we don't put a/the/my before noun. Can somebody explain me why we did that here?"

**The statement above is not accurate**:

I was bitten by a dog, not a cat. [general statement]
I was bitten by the dog in the street, not the one in the house. [specific statement]
I was bitten by his dog last night. [specific statement]
I was bitten by dogs three times when I was a kid. [general statement plural]

The dog bit me. [active sentence]
I was bitten by the dog or a dog. [passive sentence]

Answer (score 0):

In English, there are words which show how many of something there are.

- ***one*** car
- ***two*** cars
- **three** cars
- **a** car
- **some** cars
- **all** cars
- **the** car

All of these words specify the number of cars (the quantity of cars)

The word "*by*" is usually followed by a word which specifies the quantity of things performing an action

- Matthew was annoyed *by* ***the*** salesman
- Lisa was startled *by* ***all*** of the geese she saw in the park.
- Erin stood transfixed *by* ***a*** puppy she saw in the window.
- Aaron was robbed *by* ***two*** men wearing Guy Fawkes masks.